# Getting mp3 duration storaged in google app engine cloud storage

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, mp3, google-cloud-storage, duration

I have mp3 files storaged in Google App Engine Cloud Storage and I want to get their durations.
I made this code with help from one guy here but unfortunately the class AudioSystem doesn't work with the Google App Engine Cloud Storage.
Does someone know a way to do it?

```
ListResult lr = gcsService.list(mybucketname, ListOptions.DEFAULT);
while (lr.hasNext() && playlistLength > 0) {
ListItem li = lr.next();
String filename = li.getName();
GcsService gcsService =
GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(RetryParams.getDefaultInstance());
GcsInputChannel readChannel = gcsService.openPrefetchingReadChannel(new GcsFilename(mybucketName, fileName), 0, 1024 * 1024);
AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
try (InputStream in = Channels.newInputStream(readChannel)) {
audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);
}
long frames = audioInputStream.getFrameLength();
double durationInSeconds = (frames+0.0) / format.getFrameRate();
playlistLength-=(int)(durationInSeconds)/60;
```

Here is the error returned :

```
Error for /hello java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem is a restricted class. 
Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details. 
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.stub.javax.sound.sampled.AudioSyst‌​em.<clinit>(AudioSystem.java)
```

Comment: what do you mean "doesn't work"? we need more info.

Comment: That's all I have from the stack trace:
Error for /hello
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.

Comment: then..... did you see the google app engine developer's guide for more details before coming here? :)

Comment: Yes. And I couldn't find another way to do it.

Comment: so, what info did you get from the "restricted class"? It should point you towards why it doesn't work, and then you can extrapolate your solution based on why it doesn't work

Comment: what can I underdstand from this:
Error for /hello
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.
 at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.stub.javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.<clinit>(AudioSystem.java)

Comment: from this, you should understand that the app engine doc should include something about "restricted classes". Looking it up, I find this https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/?csw=1#Java_The_sandbox that explains that you cannot do many system calls. So your best bet is to save the length of your mp3 as metadata elsewhere.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand you properly.
which of my code is making system calls? and what do you mean by saving the length of my mp3 as metadata elsewhere? TY.

Comment: well looking at the fact the "AudioSystem" is a restricted class, I'd assume the system call is sent from there. And saving the length of your mp3 as data on the datastore as you upload the mp3 could be a workaround the fact the library doesn't let you get it. You wouldn't need to have your library retrieve the length, you could just get the Datastore entity linked to your mp3 and it would contain the info you need

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. TY I will try it and update.

Comment: also, quick google retrieves a lot of results how to parse mp3 file in java -different libs (most of them are outdated, but I guess will work for you) and manual parsing (it's simple format, seems that it's just dozen of lines)

Comment: Ok now it's working with @Patrice advice. Thanks!

Comment: @davidmoshko Happy to have helped. I added an answer and edited your stacktrace into your question ^^

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the issue and the doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/?csw=1#Java_The_sandbox), there's a good chance your issue is not solvable with this library, as it is currently restricted because it's making some kind of system call that the platform won't let you do.

You have multiple solutions available to you. I would suggest, when you upload the file, uploading an entity to the datastore containing the metadata and retrieving that instead.

You can also parse the file yourself and read the duration from it (mp3 being a pretty simple format, as [Igor Artamonov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/222467/igor-artamonov) is pointing out).